# Is there a universal way to set a wallpaper on Linux?

Tags: java, linux, gnome, wallpaper, kde-plasma

I am building a program that periodically changes your wallpaper with one taken from reddit. It currently supports windows, but I would like it to work also on Linux. The program is developed in Java.

The problem is that each DE has its unique way of changing a wallpaper: [XFCE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/596070/how-to-change-wallpaper-on-xfce-from-terminal), [Cinnamon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59653/change-desktop-wallpaper-from-terminal), [GNOME](https://superuser.com/questions/258568/changing-ubuntu-wallpaper-using-terminal-or-from-command-line) etc.

I wanted to find a simple universal way to do this. This is my code so far (it uses the XFCE solution because my machine runs on XFCE):

```java
public static void setWallpaper(String wallpaperPath) { 
    String s = "xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen0/monitorVGA-1/workspace0/last-image -s \"" + wallpaperPath + "\"";
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder().command("bash", "-c", s);
    Process process = processBuilder.start();
}
```

I already tried with `xwallpaper` but it just doesn't work, no change, no output, no error.

Comment: *The problem is that the each DE has its unique way of changing a wallpaper:* Yes, so you probably need to develop heuristics for each DE. You want a script for each and a way of detecting each. `uname -a` might do it for you. Once you've tested those, `ProcessBuilder` should do it for you.

Comment: There isn't a universal way.  There are various OS-specific ways ... and the simplest is to run a (system specific) command to do it.  But this will depend on the relevant applications already being installed.  Question: why are you trying to do this in a Java desktop application?  Surely, it is not the app's concern.

Comment: @StephenC what do you mean by "Java desktop application"? (sorry for the ignorance but i'm kinda new to developing)

Comment: And application written in Java that is designed to run on or be run from the user's "desktop".

Comment: @StephenC this is for a project of mine where the wallpaper gets changed periodically. I needed a way to change wallpaper also on linux, so I needed to implement this thing somehow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the best solution i found, but I bet it could be improved. I scan `$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` first and then `$GDM_SESSION` (apparently the xdg doesn't always existas an environment variable). Then I act based on what environment I found and set the wallpaper.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String wpPath = "/path/to/file";
        String os = System.getProperty("os.name");
        switch (os) {
            case "Windows 10":
                System.out.println("WINODWS DETECTED");
                break;
            case "Linux":
                String de = identifyDE();
                if (de == null) {
                    System.out.println("Couldn't identify your Desktop Environment"); // log Severe
                    break;
                }

                switch (de) {
                    case "xfce":
                        executeProcess("xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen0/monitorVGA-1/workspace0/last-image -s \"" + wpPath + "\"");
                        break;
                    case "gnome":
                        executeProcess("gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background draw-background false && gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri \"file://" + wpPath + "\" && gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background draw-background true");
                        break;
                    case "kde":
                        executeProcess("qdbus org.kde.plasmashell /PlasmaShell org.kde.PlasmaShell.evaluateScript 'var allDesktops = desktops();print (allDesktops);for (i=0;i<allDesktops.length;i++) {d = allDesktops[i];d.wallpaperPlugin = \"org.kde.image\";d.currentConfigGroup = Array(\"Wallpaper\", \"org.kde.image\", \"General\");d.writeConfig(\"Image\", \"" + wpPath + "\")}'");
                        break;
                    case "unity":
                        executeProcess("gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri \"file://" + wpPath + "\"");
                        break;
                    case "cinnamon":
                        executeProcess("gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.background picture-uri  \"file://" + wpPath + "\"");
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Can't recognize DE: " + de);
                }


                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Can't recognize OS: " + os);
        }
    }

public static String identifyDE() {
        String de;
        de = System.getenv("XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP").toLowerCase();

        if (de.contains("xfce")) {
            return "xfce";
        } else if (de.contains("kde")) {
            return "kde";
        } else if (de.contains("unity")) {
            return "unity";
        } else if (de.contains("gnome")) {
            return "gnome";
        } else if (de.contains("cinnamon")) {
            return "cinnamon";
        } else if (de.contains("mate")) {
            return "mate";
        } else if (de.contains("deepin")) {
            return "deepin";
        } else if (de.contains("budgie")) {
            return "budgie";
        } else if (de.contains("lxqt")) {
            return "lxqt";
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not identifiable with: echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP: " + de);
        }

        de = System.getenv("GDM_SESSION").toLowerCase();

        if (de.contains("xfce")) {
            return "xfce";
        } else if (de.contains("kde")) {
            return "kde";
        } else if (de.contains("unity")) {
            return "unity";
        } else if (de.contains("gnome")) {
            return "gnome";
        } else if (de.contains("cinnamon")) {
            return "cinnamon";
        }  else if (de.contains("mate")) {
            return "mate";
        } else if (de.contains("deepin")) {
            return "deepin";
        } else if (de.contains("budgie")) {
            return "budgie";
        } else if (de.contains("lxqt")) {
            return "lxqt";
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not identifiable with: echo $GDM_SESSION: " + de);
        }

        return null;
    }

public static String executeProcess(String s) {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-c", s);
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = null;
        try {
            p = pb.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                res.append(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return res.toString();
    }
```

This piece of code does need further testing as for now it has been tested only on manjaro XFCE and manjaro KDE, I'm not even sure about some of the names (deepin's XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP contains "deepin" or "dde"?). However I think it's a good solution (or a backbone for one) so I'm posting this anyway.

Sources:

- [XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP and GDM_SESSION](https://askubuntu.com/a/227669)
- [KDE](https://superuser.com/a/1332325)
- [GNOME](https://superuser.com/a/409073)
- [Unity](https://askubuntu.com/a/69500)
- [Mint](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/119224)

Comment: Yes ... this is the only approach that will work.  Note that it will only work for the set of environments that you implement it for.  And that is the problem with this approach.